# Broke my code in several class now Empty Jframe shows up after running

Tags: java, swing

Hello every one i am new to java programming I made a temp conversion calculator it works fine If I keep all of my code in this one adittion method but if i divide it in different classes empty JFrame shows up after I run this Program...

here is my data file :

```
public class DataClass extends JFrame {

    JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
    JPanel cp = new JPanel();
    JLabel lbl_1 = new JLabel("Celcius");
    JLabel lbl_2 = new JLabel("Fahrienheit");
    JTextField tf_1 = new JTextField();
    JTextField tf_2 = new JTextField();
    JButton convert = new JButton("Convert");
    JButton reset = new JButton("Reset");
    JButton exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
    JRadioButton c1toc2 = new JRadioButton("Celcius to Fahreinheit");
    JRadioButton c2toc1 = new JRadioButton("Fahreiheit to Celcius");
    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();

    String celcius = "";
    String farheinheit = "";

    double celc = 0, farh = 0;

    public void Addition() {

        cp.add(lbl_1);
        cp.add(lbl_2);
        cp.add(tf_1);
        cp.add(tf_2);
        cp.add(convert);
        cp.add(reset);
        cp.add(exitButton);
        cp.add(c1toc2);
        cp.add(c2toc1);

        group.add(c1toc2);
        group.add(c2toc1);

        myFrame.add(cp);

        lbl_1.setBounds(20, 15, 60, 50);
        tf_1.setBounds(100, 25, 200, 25);
        lbl_2.setBounds(20, 100, 80, 50);
        tf_2.setBounds(100, 110, 200, 25);
        convert.setBounds(20, 180, 100, 30);
        reset.setBounds(140, 180, 100, 30);
        exitButton.setBounds(260, 180, 100, 30);
        c1toc2.setBounds(20, 220, 150, 25);
        c2toc1.setBounds(20, 250, 150, 25);

        tf_2.setEditable(false);
        tf_1.setEditable(false);

        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        myFrame.setLayout(null);
        myFrame.setSize(400, 400);
        myFrame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

here is my action Listener file :

```
public class Temperature extends DataClass {

    public Temperature() {

        convert.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                convertActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        reset.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                resetActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        exitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                exitButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        c1toc2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                ctofActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        c2toc1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                ftocActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
    }

    private void convertActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        if (c1toc2.isSelected()) {
            String celcius = tf_1.getText();
            double celc = Double.parseDouble(celcius);
            double farh = (celc * 1.8) + 32;
            String farheinheit = String.valueOf(farh);
            tf_2.setText(farheinheit);
            tf_1.setEditable(false);
            tf_2.setEditable(false);
        }

        else if (c2toc1.isSelected()) {
            String farheinheit = tf_2.getText();
            double farh = Double.parseDouble(farheinheit);
            double celc = ((farh * 5) / 9) - 32;
            String celcius = String.valueOf(celc);
            tf_1.setText(celcius);
            tf_1.setEditable(false);
            tf_2.setEditable(false);

        }

    }

    private void resetActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

        tf_1.setText("");
        tf_2.setText("");
        tf_1.setEditable(false);
        tf_2.setEditable(false);
        group.clearSelection();
    }

    private void ctofActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

        tf_1.setEditable(true);
        tf_2.setEditable(false);
    }

    private void ftocActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

        tf_2.setEditable(true);
        tf_1.setEditable(false);
    }

    private void exitButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

here is my DriverClass :

```
public class DriverClass {
    public static void main(String args) {
        DataClass obj1 = new DataClass();
        obj1.Addition();

    }
}
```

Comment: You have some very confusing code. `DataClass` extends from `JFrame`, but you never use, you create another `JFrame` from within `DataClass` and use it instead.  As general recommendation, you shouldn't extend from `JFrame` or other top level containers, start with a `JPanel` instead and then add that to whatever container you want to use

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the child panel to the JFrame content pane.
On a related note, never ever use a null layout. Always use a proper layout manager. For complicated UI designs, you can nest layouts

Know more about layout managers here
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html